# Convert photoshop adjustement layer to SVG filter

Tags: css, svg, matrix, colors, photoshop

I am trying to replicate photoshop adjustement layers into an [SVG filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter).
I need to transform images from
[image]

[This is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQZuF.jpg)
[This is the transformed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyCQZ.jpg)

These are the 2 adjustement layers used in photoshop to create the transformed image :
[image]

I need to add this effect on hover for many images. I have tried to replicate the effect using svg [feColorMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix) but I can't figure out the right color matrix to apply the transformation.
This is the code I have tried (hover the image to see the svg filter effect) :

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}
img:hover {
  filter: url(#colorTransform);         
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQZuF.jpg" />

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="colorTransform">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" 
      values="
          1.21 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00
          0.00 1.47 0.00 0.00  0.00
          0.00 0.00 0.70 0.00  0.00
          0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00  0.00">
     </feColorMatrix>
   </filter>
</svg>
```

I tried to replicate one of the layers in the code above with the same value in the R,G and B channels but that doesn't work.

**Is there a way to generate the color matrix from the target and original images ?** Is there a way to calculate the color matrix from the adjustement layer values ?

Comment: you must add color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" to your filter element in order to set the filter to "normal" color space - otherwise it does linearRGB., And if you want an overall -24%, then you should set the fifth column to -0.24 -0.24 -0.24 0.0. The color balance adjustment would use the off-diagonal settings in feColorMatrix. You may just want to play with a feColorMatrix playground to see the closest: e.g https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/DmEYLg

Comment: @MichaelMullany thanks for the info, I will make some tests with your comment and the answer below to try and find a more robust way than guessing the matrix values.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a complete answer, but it may be of some help. I don't think there's an existing way of converting adjustment layers to an SVG color matrix.

However... you can see what the adjustment layers are doing to individual colours and [create a matrix](https://fecolormatrix.com/) accordingly

Before

[image: before adjustment]

After

[image: after adjustments]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it doesn't pin point a robust way of calulating the matrix, it make me want to push my tests further and you gave me some direction for that !